# CentOS 6.9 / Sendmail 8.14.4 / Mail gets stuck as "sending"

Tags: centos6, sendmail

We have a "mail relay" server we use for copiers, scan-to-email and some other hardware devices that need to be able to relay e-mail. We recently retired our old mail relay and brought up a new VPS with Cent6 and Sendmail 8.14.4. It works perfectly until it receives an e-mail more than a few megs in size. Once it receives a larger e-mail, the e-mail gets stuck in "Sending" (according to the mail queue screen in Webmin) and then all additional e-mails behind it just start piling up. If I go into Webmin and force the queue, boom, everything gets processed and delivered immediately.

[screenshot from webmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LExj.png)

I've watched the /var/log/maillog and /var/log/messages and I don't see any errors, any indications of problems or any timeouts.

I'm not sure what else to look for at this point.

Thank you.

Robert

Comment: Could you provide the relevant long entries? [More hints]

Comment: Yes. I had to scrub it a bit.

https://pastebin.com/d20X4Hpg

Comment: Do you use any anti-spam and anti-virus email scanners on the servers? [Sendmail queues message when system load is high.  Scanning big messages may be CPU/IO costly]

Comment: I thought A/V or a spam scanner might be at play too, but nothing there. The CPU and IO load on this box are super low. It's a 4 core box with 16g of ram, for relaying a few e-mails an hour.

What's really odd is, when I look at the mail queue in Webmin, it simply shows the e-mail as Sending... when it's really just sitting there.

Comment: Are you interested in sendmail solutions/configurations for faster sending queued messages? [Much shorter average queue time - a few minutes] BTW Do you use `SingleThreadDelivery` or `HostStatusDirectory` ?

Comment: I'm interested in finding out what is causing the messages to show as Sending and just get stuck there. We have an older Cent/Sendmail server that is (as best we can tell) identical in configuration that doesn't have this issue.

Not sure on the last two items, I don't see them listed in webmin.

Comment: does `sendmail -bh` / `hoststat` show any cached connectivity info?  Sendmail is VERY configurable.  "Guess the config option"  game may tak **long**.